# How to vertically or horizontally center a Widget in a Stack?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

The `Center` widget centers a widget horizontally and vertically in the center of a Stack. How can one center a widget ONLY horizontally or vertically?

Centering a widget in a Stack is possible with a Row or Column widget. Can it be done without using those widgets?

Conditions:

- Cannot use Row / Column.
- The size of the Stack is not known before layout (cannot use hardcoded Positioned values).

Center widget:

[image: Centered Widget in Stack]

```
Container(
      decoration:
          BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black87, width: 10)),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Container(color: Colors.amber, width: 50, height: 50),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Center horizontally w/Row:

[image: Horizontally centered widget in Stack]

`Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center)`

Center vertically w/Column:

[image: Vertically centered Widget in Stack]

`Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center)`

The alignment above is the desired result. Can those results be achieved with other Flutter widgets?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `Align` Widget

```
 Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter, // This will horizontally center from the top
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black87, width: 10)),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(color: Colors.amber, width: 50, height: 50),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
```

**1. For Top Center use alignment:**  `Alignment.topCenter`

[image]

**2. For Center Left use alignment:**  `Alignment.centerLeft`

[image]

**3. For Center right use alignment:**  `Alignment.centerRight`

[image]

**3. For Bottom center use alignment:**  `Alignment.bottomCenter`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you have a suggestion for setting the position to say "50 pixels left-of-center"?

Comment: Also, is there Constraints based solution similar to Android's Constraint Layout properties?

Comment: There is no such Widget till yet, but you can use Positions with MediaQuery which will behave same on all devices.